# Compile-time error, parameters recognized as references

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors

Inside of a class called Castle I have the following 2 functions:

```
vector<Location> Castle::getMoves(Location*** squares, Location* loc){
    int row = loc->getRow();
    int col = loc->getCol();

    vector<Location> moves;

    //problem is here!
    getVerticalMoves(squares, &moves, row, col);

    return moves;
}

void Castle::getVerticalMoves(Location*** squares, vector<Location*> * moves, int row, int col){
    //need to do something here, but can't call the function!
}
```

When I try to compile, I get an error that looks like this:

```
model/src/Castle.cpp: In member function ‘std::vector<Location> Castle::getMoves(Location***, Location*)’:
model/src/Castle.cpp:26:44: error: no matching function for call to ‘Castle::getVerticalMoves(Location***&, std::vector<Location>*, int&, int&)’
model/inc/Castle.h:38:8: note: candidate is: void Castle::getVerticalMoves(Location***, std::vector<Location*>*, int, int)
make: *** [model/obj/Castle.o] Error 1
```

I do not understand why this error is appearing. Why does it say that I am passing it references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want a vector of `Location`s? Or do you want a vector of pointers to `Location`s? You need to pick one and stick with it.

The reason it shows a reference is because if it showed just the value, that would suggest that you could not call a function that takes a reference, since a reference can appear on the left side of an equals sign and a value cannot. What you passed to the function *can* appear on the left side of an equals sign, so leaving off the & would make the error message less informative. (Suggesting perhaps your mistake was to pass a value where a modifiable reference was required.)

Consider:

```
int f1(int &j) { j++; return 3; }
int f2(int j) { return j+1; }
int q;

f1(3); // not legal, we are passing an 'int' value and need an 'int' reference
f2(3); // legal, passing an 'int' value function needs an 'int' value
f1(q); // legal, we are passing an 'int&', function need an 'int&'
f2(q); // legal, reference can be demoted to value
```

So when you pass an lvalue (something that can appear on the left side of an equal sign), you really are calling the function with a reference -- something more powerful than a mere value.

Comment: I'll remembering the ignoring references thing. Do you know why the compiler prints it that way if it's meaningless?

Comment: I added the real explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `Castle::getVerticalMoves` method takes a `vector<Location*>*` as it's second argument, whereas where you're calling it you're passing a `vector<Location>*`

ie. You're trying to send a vector of Location, to a method that is expecting a vector of pointers to Location.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're passing an std::vector* to an std::vector*.  Be consistent with your datatypes.  If you intend to pass a pointer to a vector of pointers, then pass that.